# Separating tab headers and the tab content in WPF TabControl

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I want to put a textbox under the tab headers (just like Google Chrome and such) and the tab content under that text box

So it would be like this:

```
<!-- Tab Headers -->
<TextBox x:Name="txtUrl" />
<!-- Tab Content-->
```

I've looked everywhere and I can't seem to find a way.

I'm using WPF.

Any ideas? 
Thanks.

EDIT:

[This is my current view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Leglu.png)

I am trying to make it like this

[You can see the tab headers and tab content behind separated by a panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j27jH.png)

Comment: You have to define a [Header Template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.gridview.columnheadertemplate?view=netframework-4.8) which not only includes the text, but also the TextBox you desire to have.

Comment: Could you please provide a screenshot of the style you desire to achive?

Comment: @RenéCarannante Could you provide me with an example for a Tab Control if possible?

Also, I will update the question with the style I desire.

Comment: Ok I got the wrong idea of what you want, just by the text. You will have to hide the the original tabheader and mimmic the behaviour using a stackpanel and custom controls... there is no easy way around, as far as I know.

Comment: That would seem like an appropriate solution, I suppose I could try that, although I hoped for an easier solution since it would take some time to re-implement the features of what a TabControl would do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would require you to define a custom `ControlTemplate` to which you can add a `TextBox`:

```
<TabControl>
    <TabItem Header="1">
        <TextBlock>content...</TextBlock>
    </TabItem>
    <TabItem Header="2" />
    <TabItem Header="2" />
    <TabControl.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TabControl}">

            <Grid x:Name="templateRoot" ClipToBounds="true" SnapsToDevicePixels="true" KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Local">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition x:Name="ColumnDefinition0"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition x:Name="ColumnDefinition1" Width="0"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition x:Name="RowDefinition0" Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition x:Name="RowDefinition1" Height="*"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="0,0,0,1" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                    <TabPanel x:Name="headerPanel" Background="Transparent" Grid.Column="0" IsItemsHost="true" Margin="2,2,2,0" Grid.Row="0" KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex="1" Panel.ZIndex="1"/>
                </Border>
                <Border Grid.Row="1" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="1,0,1,0" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                    <TextBox Margin="10" />
                </Border>
                <Border x:Name="contentPanel" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="1,0,1,1" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Grid.Column="0" KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Contained" Grid.Row="2" KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex="2" KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Local">
                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="PART_SelectedContentHost" ContentSource="SelectedContent" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                </Border>
            </Grid>
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                    <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}"/>
                </Trigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </TabControl.Template>
</TabControl>
```

Comment: That is a good way, but I found some alignment problems with it which is just, a big mess. To be clear, I'm supposed to put the controls I want in the Border between the headerPanel and the contentPanel, yes?

Comment: @OsayedZaheda: Yes, in this particular example but you can define the template however you want. The headers will be inserted where you put the `<TabPanel>` element and the content where you put the `<ContentPresenter>`.

Comment: I do not intend on just using stackoverflow to make the code for me, I intend to understand the code so that I can re-create it myself which is why I asked that question above. But thank you I will try that right away.